# MatLab data loop

Tags: matlab, loops, datatable, ascii

I have this code in order to make NetCDF data into ASCII table. I'll simplify it that way:

```
lat = 1:193
lon = 1:361

whole_bin = 1:69673
chl = ncread(filenameIN, 'CHL1_mean');

for x = 1:length(whole_bin)
    for y = 1:361
        for z = 1:193
        data(:,1) = lon(y);
        data(:,2) = lat(z);
        data(:,3) = chl(y,z);
        end
    end
end
```

The thing is, this code returns me only part of the supposed tabel:

```
...
1   1   1.27927434444428
2   1   1.38863492012024
3   1   1.38863253593445
4   1   1.38863253593445
5   1   1.38197994232178
6   1   1.21169304847717
7   1   1.21169281005859
8   1   1.21169281005859
9   1   1.21169281005859
10  1   1.18449604511261
11  1   1.18139111995697
...
```

In other words, this table is only with one latitude and all longitude. And what I really need is for every latitude the same result. So, instead of 361 rows it should be 69673, what in this sample "whole_bin" is.

```
...
1   1   1.27927434444428
2   1   1.38863492012024
3   1   1.38863253593445
4   1   1.38863253593445
5   1   1.38197994232178
6   1   1.21169304847717
7   1   1.21169281005859
8   1   1.21169281005859
9   1   1.21169281005859
10  1   1.18449604511261
11  1   1.18139111995697
...
1   2   1.27927434444428
2   2   1.38863492012024
3   2   1.38863253593445
4   2   1.38863253593445
5   2   1.38197994232178
6   2   1.21169304847717
7   2   1.21169281005859
8   2   1.21169281005859
9   2   1.21169281005859
10  2   1.18449604511261
11  2   1.18139111995697
...
1   3   1.27927434444428
2   3   1.38863492012024
3   3   1.38863253593445
4   3   1.38863253593445
5   3   1.38197994232178
6   3   1.21169304847717
7   3   1.21169281005859
8   3   1.21169281005859
9   3   1.21169281005859
10  3   1.18449604511261
11  3   1.18139111995697
...
```

Comment: We can't see your data, so this isn't trivial for us to answer. Notably though your indexing is a little odd - inside the `y` loop you only use `z` and `x` to index anything?

Comment: I tried several ways to make it work, so I guess it's just what I ended up with eventually.

Comment: `lat(z)` should likely be `lat(y)`.  But your indexing into `data` is weird too. According to your loops it should be a 4D array. Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. We cannot tell what it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: I've tried to simplify it now as much as I could.

Comment: according to your code, let's assume that `chl` is a 2D array that associates a values to each (lat, lon). Then you need not the first iteration loop on `x`, but need an index k that starts from 1 and increments inside the other two loops. And replace `data(:,1)` by `data(k,1)` and similarly in the next two lines.